# Convert CSV file into objects in a generic way

Tags: java

Ok, so i want to create a generic reading function in Java without using any other libraries(except for opencsv). (I've asked a bit about it a few hours before, and thought i sorted it out but turns out it didnt work.)

```
public class Read {

    void Reader(String fileName) {

        Map<String, String> mapping = new
                HashMap<String, String>();
        //mapping.put("Name", "Name");
        //mapping.put("Price", "Price");

        HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Product> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<>();
        strategy.setType(Product.class);
        strategy.setColumnMapping(mapping);
        ...

    }
}
```

This works. The problem is i need to make it generic, as i'd like to use it for different kinds of csv's. My generic skills are not exactly the best though. If i change it to

```
void <T> Reader(T Obj,...)
...
```

and i pass a product Obj, im not sure what to put instead of

```
#...<Product> strategy
#and strategy.setType(Product.class)
```

I've tried adding the relative path, or using Obj.class, but i keep getting cannot convert errors.
Any ideas?

*The mappings are just an example, i've tried parsing the CSV to get the object tags for any object and it works.*

More info:
Tried trampering with these:

```
public static <T> void Read(T Obj,String fileName) {
...
HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<T> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<>();
strategy.setType(Obj.getClass());
```

```
error:incompatible types: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends T>
```

Comment: can you put the error message you got when trying to do it in the generic way

Comment: @RahalKanishka added now

Answer (score 1):

The following approach aims to:

1) Provide a generic method for reading CSV data to different beans.

2) Avoid the need for casting to those different beans.

3) Provide some flexibility for different CSV structures/formats.

My example uses a `HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy`, rather than the `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy` in the question - but you can change that, as you see fit. I have a slight preference for the former, as it lets me use annotations in the beans.

### Source CSV Data:

The products.csv file:

```
Product ID,Product Name,Product Price
100125,Product One,123.45
100347,Product Two,3456.78
```

The customers.csv file:

```
Customer ID,Customer Name
4544678,John Smith
4544679,"Acme Warehouse, Inc."
```

### The Beans

These use the `com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName` annotation for my `HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy`:

```
public class Product {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Product ID")
    private long id;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Product Name")
    private String name;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Product Price")
    private double price;

    // getters and setters not shown
}
```

and:

```
public class Customer {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Customer ID")
    private String id;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Customer Name")
    private String name;

    // getters and setters not shown
}
```

### The Generic Method

This relies on the fact that [`CsvToBean`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBean.html) is a generic method. By passing a list of the required type into this method, we can avoid needing to cast the results in the calling methods:

```
private <T> List<T> readCsvToBeanList(Path path, Class clazz, List<T> list) throws Exception {
    HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy ms = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy();
    ms.setType(clazz);

    try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
        CsvToBean cb = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                .withType(clazz)
                .withMappingStrategy(ms)
                .build();

         list = cb.parse();
    }
    return list;
}
```

The above method can be called for the two objects as follows:

```
Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("csv/products.csv").toURI());
List<Product> products = new ArrayList();
products = readCsvToBeanList(path, Product.class, products);
for (Product p : products) {
    System.out.println(p.getId()+ " - " + p.getName() + " - " + p.getPrice());
}
```

And similarly for customers:

```
Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("csv/customers.csv").toURI());
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList();
customers = readCsvToBeanList(path, Customer.class, customers);
for (Customer c : customers) {
    System.out.println(c.getId()+ " - " + c.getName());
}
```

The output from the above examples is as follows:

```
100125 - Product One - 123.45
100347 - Product Two - 3456.78

4544678 - John Smith
4544679 - Acme Warehouse, Inc.
```

**Final notes**:

This assumes we always have CSV files of a certain type - namely using comma separators, with a heading row, no empty lines, etc. So, it is brittle. Also, there is no error handling at this point. You can either pass additional parameters into the `readCsvToBeanList` method - for example a separator value:

```
CsvToBean cb = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
            .withType(clazz)
            .withMappingStrategy(ms)
            .withSeparator('\t') // or whatever char you provide
            .build();
```

Or you can build a set of `CsvToBean` objects using different pre-defined builder configurations.

This gives you a lot of flexibility, overall.

Hope this helps and can be adapted to your specific situation.